# Running a Qt5 application not full-screen, use VNC

Tags: vnc, qt

The problem : I can't run my Qt5 app as a normal X window. It is always full screen.

I successfully compiled Qt5 and I can deploy a simple program to the RPi : Qt Creator uploads the executable to the RPi and runs it. The widget shows up full-screen on a HDMI attached monitor. The problem is that I can't switch applications, and I can't view the program widget on another computer screen (ubuntu or windows).

I configured a VNC server on the RPi, which works fine. I'd like to run the RPi without a monitor and connect via VNC from time to time to check my program. Ssh X forwarding doesn't work either.

```
configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/USERNAME/opt/rpi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/rpi -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -no-pch -qt-xcb
```

And the config.summary file contents :

```
       Configure summary

    Building on:   linux-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
    Building for:  devices/linux-rasp-pi-g++ (arm, CPU features:)
    Platform notes:

                - Also available for Linux: linux-kcc linux-icc linux-cxx

    Build options:
      Configuration .......... accessibility audio-backend c++11 clock-gettime clock-monotonic compile_examples concurrent cross_compile egl eglfs evdev eventfd freetype full-config getaddrinfo getifaddrs iconv inotify ipv6ifname large-config largefile linuxfb medium-config minimal-config mremap nis no-harfbuzz opengl opengles2 pcre png posix_fallocate qpa qpa reduce_exports release rpath shared small-config system-zlib xcb xcb-plugin xcb-qt xkbcommon-qt xlib
      Build parts ............  libs
      Mode ................... release
      Using C++11 ............ yes
      Using PCH .............. no
      Target compiler supports:
        iWMMXt/Neon .......... no/auto

    Qt modules and options:
      Qt D-Bus ............... no
      Qt Concurrent .......... yes
      Qt GUI ................. yes
      Qt Widgets ............. yes
      Large File ............. yes
      QML debugging .......... yes
      Use system proxies ..... no

    Support enabled for:
      Accessibility .......... yes
      ALSA ................... no
      CUPS ................... no
      Evdev .................. yes
      FontConfig ............. no
      FreeType ............... yes (bundled copy)
      Glib ................... no
      GTK theme .............. no
      HarfBuzz ............... no
      Iconv .................. yes
      ICU .................... no
      Image formats:
        GIF .................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
        JPEG ................. yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
        PNG .................. yes (in QtGui, using bundled copy)
      journald ............... no
      mtdev .................. no
      Networking:
        getaddrinfo .......... yes
        getifaddrs ........... yes
        IPv6 ifname .......... yes
        OpenSSL .............. no
      NIS .................... yes
      OpenGL / OpenVG:
        EGL .................. yes
        OpenGL ............... yes (OpenGL ES 2.x)
        OpenVG ............... no
      PCRE ................... yes (bundled copy)
      pkg-config ............. yes
      PulseAudio ............. no
      QPA backends:
        DirectFB ............. no
        EGLFS ................ yes
        KMS .................. no
        LinuxFB .............. yes
        XCB .................. yes (bundled copy)
          EGL on X ........... no
          GLX ................ no
          MIT-SHM ............ yes
          Xcb-Xlib ........... no
          Xcursor ............ yes (loaded at runtime)
          Xfixes ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
          Xi ................. yes (loaded at runtime)
          Xi2 ................ no
          Xinerama ........... yes (loaded at runtime)
          Xrandr ............. yes (loaded at runtime)
          Xrender ............ no
          XKB ................ yes
          XShape ............. yes
          XSync .............. yes
          XVideo ............. yes
      Session management ..... yes
      SQL drivers:
        DB2 .................. no
        InterBase ............ no
        MySQL ................ no
        OCI .................. no
        ODBC ................. no
        PostgreSQL ........... no
        SQLite 2 ............. no
        SQLite ............... yes (plugin, using bundled copy)
        TDS .................. no
      udev ................... no
      xkbcommon .............. yes (bundled copy, XKB config root: /usr/share/X11/xkb)
      zlib ................... yes (system library)

    NOTE: libxkbcommon and libxkbcommon-x11 0.4.1 or higher not found on the system, will use
    the bundled version from 3rd party directory.
    NOTE: Qt is using double for qreal on this system. This is binary incompatible against Qt 5.1.
    Configure with '-qreal float' to create a build that is binary compatible with 5.1.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Someone finally gave me the solution at http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/193543/
In short :

```
./program -platform xcb
```